# copying node and replace value in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to copy and replace a value in xlst but i get a blank value

```
<xsl:template match="/Tests/test/comment">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="NEW"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I get

```
<comment></comment>
```

i want

```
<comment>NEW</comment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value-of` takes a value of a node named `NEW` in the current context. I don't think this is that you meant to do.
Try

```
<xsl:template match="/Tests/test/comment">
    <xsl:copy>NEW</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your word NEW in single quotes like this:

```
  <xsl:value-of select="'NEW'"/>
```